# After installing Blackberry Java plug-in in Eclipse cannot see the option for running the blackberry project

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have being developing application using android on Eclipse Helios(Windows XP).
Now i want to develop it for blackberry, and for that i found the following links

http://thinkingblackberry.com/?p=260

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp

Now installation ran smoothly, i can see the blackberry installed in HELP -> ABOUT option in Eclipse. but when i started Eclipse i cannot see the option's for blackberry.

Comment: better to use two different eclipse so download different eclips for blackberry

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the menu on the upper right border of eclipse?

[image: Have you tryed the menu on the upper right border of eclipse?]

Comment: I cannot see that option, there are only two remaining options available.

Comment: i was talking the same, i cannot see blackberry option.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window->Open Perspective->BlackBerry Application Development

There you have it.